# как обойти ограничение max_execution_time в php?

Tags: php, javascript

есть сервер, на котором `max_execution_time` выставлен в `30` секунд.
условимся, что изменить его значение нельзя.

стоит задача на таком сервере выполнять тяжелые вычисления (например, парсинг множества страниц), которые могут занять несколько часов времени. как можно решить такую проблему? может есть готовые примеры на `github` или еще где-нибудь?

приходит в голову использовать периодические `ajax` запросы на скрипт, который будет обрабатывать данные небольшими порциями (чтобы уложиться в ограничения). там можно и прогресс-бар сделать с результатами работы.

в связи с этим возникают вопросы - что будет с `js` кодом, отправляющим `ajax` запросы, если вкладка браузера станет неактивной? слышал, что выполнение `js` кода может быть приостановлено. также хотелось бы, чтобы решение работало и на мобильных браузерах тоже - там же могут быть свои детали работы `js` на неактивных вкладках.

в общем, посоветуйте наилучший вариант реализации

Answer (score 2):

Если оно задано хостинг-провайдером в настройках, то никак. **Master** значение всегда главнее пользовательского.

Если вы выполняете парсинг через веб-сервер, выполняя запрос на php скрипт с помощью браузера, то слава богу что там стоит такое ограничение. Выполнять ajax запросы к скрипту периодично с различными смещениями - забудьте про эту идею, как страшный сон. Ведь даже если вы разобьете задачу на маленькие порции и запуск скрипта будет нагружать сервер, хостер рано или поздно сообщить вам о том, что пора прощаться или покупайте тариф выше.

Выполнять большие и долгие скрипты только через **командную строку сервера**, где ограничения на время выполнения нет.

```
php script.php
```

Но хостинг провайдер может по сути установить и на cli режим ограничение по времени и тогда в целом Вам врятли подходит обычный хостинг для подобной задачи, здесь нужно для увеличения производительности делать многопоточность которую можно также реализовать на PHP (не кидайте в меня камни).

Самый правильный путь это очередь задач и воркеры, которые будут ее обрабатывать во столько потоков, во сколько вы хотите, тоесть вы ставите в очередь задачи с урлами страниц, а воркеры их парсят и пишут куда-то результат. Это очень удобно, напишите воркеров сначала на PHP, а потом вдруг захотите что-нибудь новенькое, перепишите на другой язык, а смысл задач останется. Можете разбить на несколько серверов эту очередь и тогда это будет еще быстрее.

Более подробную информацию ищите в Google про очереди задач, это здесь очень часто обсуждается.

Другой вариант использовать библиотеки которые позволяют создавать дополнительные потоки для PHP скрипта и этим получать многократное увеличение производительности (pthreads и другие)

**P.S.** Не поскупитесь на VPS сервер, они сейчас не такие дорогие, чтобы выполнять вашу задачу в разы быстрее и иметь полный контроль над своим сервером.